# Pagination along with question per page goes 404 - page not found

Tags: bug, pagination

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Viewing more ‘Questions per Page’ jumps to non-existent pages (“page not found”)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152675/viewing-more-questions-per-page-jumps-to-non-existent-pages-page-not-found)

I just Entered the site with default 15 per page question and in 1st page.

After I selected the last page which shows in pagination for example in stack overflow newest question 279187, it shows 14 questions.

Then I just wanted to view the page with 50 per page by clicking 50. It directly goes to 404-Page not found.

Then I just hit the back button and clicked the 279183<sup>rd</sup> (it is the next page which shown after 1st page) page still it goes to 404-Page not found...

Here i was saying that after i give the back button it must reset to previous no.of.records but it doesnt..!

Comment: This happens on all sites rather than just Stack Overflow, the page number is in the URL rather than the highest question number so whilst there *are* 279189 pages of 15 questions to page there are only about 8400 pages of 15 questions.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21627/pagination-fails-when-changing-questions-per-page?rq=1 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22887/pagenation-hiccup?lq=1 are the same problem, both marked [status-completed] interestingly enough.